iOS 18: contentShape interaction breaks scroll functionality
Here is a simple code. The problem is that in iOS 18 scroll in TextEditor doesn't work (but in previous OS it works properly). I would appreciate any help (workaround) for this problem.
        ZStack {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
            
            Color.clear
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .contentShape(.interaction, Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    //...
                }
        }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your Color.clear is on top of your TextEditor (because you are using ZStack) and is getting all interactions instead of the TextEditor that is under.

@workingdogsupportUkraine thx for response. Yes you're right, but why this code is working on previous iOS versions? And how is possible workaround this problem? Thanks!

It's hard to believe it worked on previous iOS, but I cannot test this.
Don't understand what you want to achieve with this kind of code.
Try this approach, having the Color.clear background first, then on top of that
the TextEditor with a given frame.
Example code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear // Background color first
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .contentShape(.interaction, Rectangle())
                .border(.blue) // <-- for testing
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("----> onTapGesture")
                }
            
            TextEditor(text: $text) // TextEditor on top
                .border(.red) // <-- for testing
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 222)
        }
    }
}

